# Socket UDP from local computer, Error code 10049

Tags: winforms, sockets

i have been searching the web for a solution, but no luck.

We are making a socket, that can send and recieve data. Both the client and server version are acting as a client and server. The problem is, that the client server version ip is on a network that use NAT, which means, that  when the server is trying to recieve the message, it wont, because the server have the public ip and we cant seem to find a solution, for how to recieve the data.

The SetIPProtectionLevel is Unrestricted, so it should work.

Thanks for the help.

We have tried to change the ip on the server version to local and then send from client to public server ip, but with no luck.

From local client ip to local server ip it is working.

Comment: It should work just fine. The 10049 error means you're using the wrong address. If the problem is that you're getting that error code, it's due to a bug in your code which you need to find and fix. What operation is getting that error? What parameters are you passing in that operation?

Comment: here can you see the server code:
                SN = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                IPEndPoint IEP = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);
                SN.SetIPProtectionLevel(IPProtectionLevel.Unrestricted);
                SN.Bind(IEP);

                IPEndPoint IPS = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("[my ip]"), 2000);

                EndPoint EP = (EndPoint)IPS;
                SN.BeginReceiveFrom(BR, 0, BR.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref EP, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), EP);

Comment: That can't work for the server! You can't know the IP/port until you receive a UDP packet and you can't receive a UDP packet until after you have the socket set up! You need to bind long before you receive the first UDP packet, long before you know the other end's IP and port.

Comment: The wierd thing is, that on my friends computer there is no problem with the server. So i has something to do with my network compared to his

Comment: Sometimes when you break the rules, it works by luck. But the rules exist for a reason. (And that's what's happening here. It's working by pure luck, the IP and port happen to match what you expect. But your expectation is unreasonable, and when it's wrong, your code breaks.)

Comment: do you have link to an article that can help us further?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason this should give you any problems, provided that one side is not behind NAT and the side that's behind NAT sends the first packet. Just follow these rules:

1) On the server, check the list of all IP addresses the host has. Bind a UDP socket to *each* IP address. You can skip this if the server only has one public IP address and that's the only address it will be reached on.

2) Send a UDP reply on precisely the same socket you received the request on. This is critical to ensure the source address of the reply matches the destination address.

3) Send the UDP reply to precisely the same IP address and port as you received the query on. Ignore anything the other end says about what it thinks its IP address is or what port it thinks it's sending from.

And a few notes:

By "the server", I mean the side that's not behind NAT. If you have no distinction between client and server, then follow the server rules for both sides and you'll be fine.

These rules apply whether or not a packet is, strictly speaking, a reply. They apply to any packet you expect to get to the other side.

Remember, you can't rely on the IP/port information in the packet to tell you who the packet came from, because NAT can change it. So you will have to put sufficient information in the payload of the datagram to do that. Ideally, expect that an endpoint's IP/port can change at any time and send all packets to the IP/port from which you last received a packet from that particular client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your AntiVirus software installed.

We had to find out that some AV sw broke our interprocess communication built upon UDP messaging - even when the AV included firewall part was deactivated and our own sw was put on the trusted sw list.
Some AV products seem to stick themselves so deep in the IP stack and do weird things to filter out suspicious communication that there may be strange effects. The only thing which helped was deinstalling the AV protection sw.

Support of most AV companies for such problems was very poor - so we finally had to change to another AV sw brand.